# String.strip() Importance

Tags: python, string, file, strip

I had the task of writing a function that compares the length of the words in a file to an integer and then returns all the words that are that size. The answer I got was almost identical except I didn't include a string.strip() like they did:

```
def get_words(dictfile,size): words = []
  for word in open(dictfile).readlines():
      word = word.strip() #this is the only bit I didn't have in my own code
      if len(word) == size:
          words.append(word) 
  return words
```

Would leaving the .strip() out really change the output of this function or is it just good practice to put it in when working with files?

EDIT:
The input would be a file where every word is one a single line e.g.

```
a
abandon
abbey
abdominal
```

and the size is just any integer

Comment: Not that this is off-topic, but this seems more of a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Future reference at least if you didn't know of that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have an effect depending on your input. Meaning it is probably best to have it in there.

Given you are reading one word per line, the `strip()` exists to remove leading or trailing whitespace. E.G.:

```
word1
  word2
word3
```

`word2` will show a greater length than the others without `strip()`. This also applies if the whitespaces come afterwards, which is also much harder to spot by looking at your input file (I can't even find a good way to represent it visually in this answer)

*Edit:*
As @Two-Bit Alchemist pointed out in the comments the `\n` character needs to be stripped also otherwise you have an off-by-1 error. This character is used as a line ending so isn't usually noticed by us humans, but the Python interpreter takes it into account.

Comment: There's an off-by-one error associated with not using `strip()` here, whether trailing whitespace exists or not, because it's counting the `'\n'` as part of the "length of the word".

Comment: You're completely correct, not sure how I missed that... Thanks, I'll edit to fix.

Comment: `trailing` means following, not preceding. I know film trailers precede the film's release, but they used to be shown as adverts *after* the main feature.

Comment: @PeterWood At the risk of showing my (lack of) age, I didn't know that's why they were called film trailers. Thanks for the neat etymology!

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_number_of_words(filename, size):
    words = []
    with open(filename) as dictfile:
        for line in dictfile:
            word = line.strip()
            if len(word) == size:
                words.append(word)
    return words
```

I rewrote your function with some more "call-a-spade-a-spade" variable names to clear up what's going on. Let's talk about some things I replaced:

- `for word in open(dictfile).readlines():`

By opening the file anonymously this way, you have thrown away your reference to the file object that you would use to close it. Additionally, you have needlessly read the entire file into memory with `readlines`. Instead, I prefer the `with` context manager, which allows you to save the reference to the file handle (using `as`), and automatically closes the file after you are finished, which you neglected to do. (Technically Python will do this for you eventually but it's still a good habit.)

Notice also that I iterate directly over the file `for line in dictfile` -- this is much more efficient than front-loading the entire file into memory.

---

As for your title question, it is absolutely essential to call `line.strip()` here if you wish for this function to provide an accurate count. Each line in the file you iterate over contains a `'\n'` character (newline), which is counted by `len`, as it is part of the string. As you have it, if you asked the function how many words of length 4 were in the file, it would give you all the words of length 3 (the 4th character being `'\n'` which a human wouldn't typically count).

Comment: Oops, sorry guys. Thanks. That's what I get for typing code on here and not in an interpreter :P

Answer (score 1):

Adding some more points on top of @Knells answer, 
    **String.Strip()** function is not only used to remove the trailing whitespace when none provided as argument for strip ,It can remove any character or character list you specify as arguments from the **end and beginning** the string for e.g..

```
str1 = " Saltharion   "
//will result in "Saltharion"
str1.Strip() 

str2 = "ooHow are yuoo"
// Will result in "How are yu", here the char "o" at the `end and beginning` is stripped from string
str2.strip("o") 

str3 = "ar How are you, I am good are" 
// will result in "How are you, I am good", here it will not strip occurrence of "are" it will strip occurrence of "a" "r" "e" from end and beginning
str3.strip("are")
```

Please look in to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)